# Get ARFrame from ARKit scene

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I am new to iPhone app development (but experienced developer in other languages) and I am making an ARKit application in which I need to track an image's position and display a rectangle around this image.

I could do it in C++ with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) and make the appropriate "bridging" classes to be able to call this code from swift. Now, I need to get the images from ARKit and pass them to this function.

How do I suscribe a function which handles the `ARFrame`s from the ARKit scene? I found that I could get some `ARFrame` from `sceneView.session.currentFrame` but I did not find how to make a function that would be called for each frame (or each time my function has ended and is ready to receive the next frame).

Also, I discovered the [Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) but it seems to only be able to track an element on which the user tapped. Is that right or is there a combination of predefined functions which could be used to this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get each captured frame by the camera with the [session(:didUpdate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session) method from the `ARSessionDelegate` protocol. Note that this method might be useful even if you don't use the provided ARFrame; for instance, I use it to "poll" if there's any virtual content added currently visible.

Regarding the tracking image question, I believe you could create an [ARAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor) or [SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) and position it over the image and ARKit would track it